# cmake Python: Cannot use the interpreter

Tags: python, cmake

I am using cmake's `find_package` to locate Python3 like so:

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

This works on my system locally but on our CI it fails on some runs (once Linux and once Linux with MXE) it errors with

```
Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)

Reason given by package: 

    Interpreter: Cannot use the interpreter "/opt/pyenv/shims/python3.8"
```

On the same systems it works if I use `python3` directly to call my script. Therefore I can say for sure that they do have a working Python environment.

I am wondering what kind of checks `find_package` performs that lead it to believe that the interpreter was not working. And most importantly: How can I disable these checks?

---

Note: I can't simply rely on Python being in PATH as this assumption breaks on our Windows CI where the `find_package` approach works fine.

Note2: I am using the latest cmake version (from Kitware's PPA)

Comment: Similar issue over here using Travis-CI: CMake Error at /usr/local/cmake-3.12.4/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)

Comment: @34563578345 unfortunately I still did not find a solution to this issue yet.

Comment: For me it worked this way: I had to comment out some crappy stuff in CMakeLists.txt, maybe check the files? KR

Comment: @34563578345 what kind of stuff did you have to comment out? Do you happen to have a publicly accessibly diff link or something like that?

Comment: So you removed this part and replaced it by a regular `find_package(Python3 REQUIRED)` call? That's what I am doing - except I am also specifying a component. Maybe that's the issue...

Comment: Just commented it out/away... ci/cd runs fine after that step for me. Try?

Comment: So you're not performing any find_package magic at all? That did not work on all platforms for me. e.g. on Windows this breaks iirc

Comment: "all platforms" is a bit too much of a target for me tbh. What do you mean?

Comment: Well if you don't use `find_package` I assume you are relying on the python interpreter to be in PATH, which in my case doesn't seem to be the case for our Windows CI.

Comment: Yes, correct, I do, because I never understood this: searching for py3 if py3 is the current version anyway? Using Travis-CI...

Comment: @34563578345 in case you're interested: I solved the issue for my case (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know *why* `find_package` emitted this particular error, I was able to circumvent it by using a self-written function that locates a Python interpreter and by doing so it prefers executables found in PATH or other standard directories.

The script is available at https://github.com/Krzmbrzl/FindPythonInterpreter (including usage instructions).

In short this allowed me to use the following snippet to find a Python 3 interpreter:

```
find_python_interpreter(
    VERSION 3
    INTERPRETER_OUT_VAR PYTHON_INTERPRETER
    REQUIRED
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_package(Python3 REQUIRED)` was working fine for me and then after restarting my computer this started happening for some unknown reason. It seems to be because the path to the python interpreter is not in quotes. If I run CMake with --trace-expand then here is the test command being used: `execute_process(COMMAND  C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/python3.10.exe -c import sys; sys.stdout.write(str(sys.version_info[0])) RESULT_VARIABLE result OUTPUT_VARIABLE version ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE )`

If I run this command in the prompt I get: `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Edit: 10 minutes later after changing nothing I tried configuring again everything worked fine. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Very interesting finding! This would hint at an issue in cmake's implementation of FindPython, which for some reason only shows up every once and a while. When looking at https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake it does indeed appear as if there are several placed in which the argument to `COMMAND` is not quoted. However, in my original example, there were no spaces in the path to the executable, so it seems that at least the root problem has to be something else...